# Modulus of Riemann zeta function \zeta(\sigma+it) as a real function of t

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Define

$$ Y(t) := |\zeta(\sigma_0 + it)|,  \ \ \ \ \ \ (\frac{1}{2} < \sigma_0 < 1)$$

Is $Y(t)$ an analytic function of the real variable $t$?

**Remark** Hardy defined the function
$$ Z(t) := \zeta(\frac{1}{2} + it) (\chi(\frac{1}{2} + it))^{-1/2},$$
and showed that
$$ |Z(t)| = |\zeta(\frac{1}{2} + it)|.$$
Of course, 
$$ \zeta(\frac{1}{2} + it) (\chi(\frac{1}{2} + it))^{-1/2}$$
is analytic in a neighborhood of $(1/2,t)$ in the complex plane, and therefore real analytic in $t$.

Comment: What are your thoughts about it?

Comment: @Saket the OP is just wrong as noted in the answer below $Z =\pm |\zeta|$

Answer (score 1):

The OP is utterly wrong as $Z(t)$ is a real analytic function defined as

$Z(t) = \zeta(\frac{1}{2} + it) (\chi(\frac{1}{2} + it))^{-1/2}$ which satisfies:

$|Z(t)|=|\zeta(\frac{1}{2} + it)|$ but it is simply not true that $Z(t)=|\zeta(\frac{1}{2} + it)|$

What is true is that:

$Z(t) = \pm |\zeta(\frac{1}{2} + it)|$ and [a recent observation of Ivic](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.04711v1) shows that if $t$ is not an ordinate of a zero of $\zeta$ (not necessarily a critical zero btw, could be a presumable counterexample to RH zero), then

$Z(t)=(-1)^{N(t)+1}|\zeta(\frac{1}{2} + it)|, t>0$, where $N(t)=\sum_{0 < \gamma \le t}1$ the number of (non-trivial but could be outside critical line if any such) zeroes of RZ up to and including imaginary level $t$ (which is the definition in Titchmarsh standard textbook and not the usual convention of taking arithmetic functions with jumps to be adding half the value at jumps - there is more discussion of this subtle distinction in the note linked above)

Comment: Wow, thanks for that. Sorry for the bungle, I'm a greenhorn in the area.

Comment: @Conrad Yes I agree.....

Comment: most proofs that $\zeta$ has lots of zeroes on the critical line use precisely the reasoning that if that wasn't true $Z$ would have a constant sign so would be $|Z|$ or $-|Z|$ (one of them fixed as it generally alternates between them) on a large amount of the critical line and then integral estimates of $Z$ (smallish by various exponential sums arguments) vs $|\zeta|$ (largish by residues) are show to lead to a contradiction - titchmarsh RZ bible has details

Comment: Conrad, the *recent result of Ivic* is trivial from my answer, $|\zeta(1/2+it)|$ is real analytic away from the zeros and at a zero it is $|t-\rho|^{n_\rho}g(t)$ with $g = |\zeta(s)/(s-\rho)^{n_\rho}|$ analytic. For $n_\rho$ even $|t-\rho|^{n_\rho}$ is analytic, otherwise it needs a $sign(t-\rho)$ term to become analytic. Once we have an analytic version of $(-1)^{h(t)} |\zeta(1/2+it)|$ then it has to be unique.

Comment: @reuns - there are subtleties regarding multiple zeroes and possible non-critical zeroes, but otherwise, I quite agree it isn't that deep a result - however, there is an interesting discussion about how RH affects the above if different definitions of $N$ are used (as noted for arithmetic functions with jumps there are several conventions for the value at the jumps)

Comment: I don't agree there are subtleties, and the sum is only counting the critical line zeros. Local real analyticity implies global real analyticity and the local analyticity is trivial.

Comment: @reuns - no the whole point is to count all zeroes, in other words, the formula is true when $N(t)$ is the full zero count regardless of RH (note that any non-critical zeroes add an even number in the sum as those occur in pairs) - again I do not dispute that this is anything more than a simple observation, but it brings an interesting point regarding about how one defines arithmetic functions

Comment: @reuns - edited to change "result" with observation as I agree with your point there

Answer (score 0):

> For $f$ meromorphic then $(x,y)\to |f(x+iy)|$ is real-analytic away from the poles and the zeros-of-odd-order of $f$.

Proof : at the poles of $f$ the non-analyticity is obvious,

away from the poles $(x,y)\to \Re(f(x+iy))$ is real-analytic thus so is $(x,y)\to |f(x+iy)|^2$,

$u\to u^{1/2}$ is analytic on $(0,\infty)$,

at a zero of even order then $f=g^2$ with $g$ analytic,

it remains to check that $|f(x+iy)|$ is not smooth at the zeros of odd order, which follows from $f(z) = (z-\rho)^{2k+1} g(z),g(\rho)\ne 0$.

Note from Conard's answer : near an odd order zero $f(x_0+iy_0)=0$ the function $y\to sign(y-y_0) |f(x_0+iy)|$ is analytic, thus on OP's vertical line $\sigma_0+i\Bbb{R}$ the real analyticity can be repaired through multiplication by some $(-1)^{h_{\sigma_0}(y)}$ term, where $h_{\sigma_0}$ is counting the number of (odd order) zeros on the line.

Comment: anything unclear ?

Comment: Just saw this. Enlightened! Thanks very much indeed!